# How to permanently disable Group By in File Explorer Windows

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I would like to permanently disable or remove the "Group By" option in the "View menu" of "File Explorer" in Windows.  I can not foresee any universe in which I would want this setting.  It keeps turning itself **ON** randomly on a folder that I may be working on.

Yes, I know how to disable it for that instance.  And yes I know how to apply it all folders.  But this does not help, because it keeps turning itself **ON**.

Comment: It is generally possible to minimize the Group By occurrences as follows:  Go to the top level folder (may be more than one), turn OFF Group By, I also view Details, then View, Options and then apply  to all folders.   I never see Group By.

Comment: As mentioned, I already know how to do this, but it doesnt work for more than a few minutes.  I just have to go up a folder and down again, and it groups it .

Comment: If a view you set for a folder is not being retained, you've most likely "maxed out" on saved views. Copy & paste this command into a **PowerShell** console window & press `<Enter>`. If it returns `5000`, that's your real problem. `((gp "HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU").Nodeslots).count`

Comment: It does say 5000.  This is crazy.  I am never changing views at all, never mind 5000 times.  Welcome to flaky software !!!.  This probably also explains why the file explorer restarts several times a day.  I wish the NT had not been canned.  :-(  However, I am still looking for a registry patch to disable it altogether..  Why does it default to groping away from none ?

Comment: @KeithMiller I also reached 5000, is it safe to simply delete some/all of these registry keys ?

Comment: Yes, delete `BagMRU` and `Bags`, then sign out & back in to clear all the settings Explorer caches. Then open the user folders under This PC one at a time, and for each do the followig: `1.` set their view to your liking. `2.` Use `Apply to Folders` to set your custom default for that type. (Desktop uses the `Generic/General` type)

Answer (score 4):

WinSetView is made to fix this.

https://lesferch.github.io/WinSetView/

Comment: It would be really useful to post an answer on *how* to fix the problem with this tool - that's to say the process, rather than posting just a link, so folks with the same issue can see your answer and make a judgement based on *this* site alone whether the tool is worth checking out

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).