# How do I reduce the number of "saved views" on my system so that I can "long-term" disable GROUP BY

Tags: windows-explorer

I was looking for a way to prevent any Explorer folder from "Grouping", permanently. ([original posting here](https://superuser.com/questions/1675696/how-to-permanently-disable-group-by-in-file-explorer-windows)) I did find soft of an answer, but the problem with it is that the member (Kevin Miller) who suggested such a good answer only showed what the problem was, not how to fix it. Specifically, his solution only showed that, indeed, the person asking the question (and myself, as well) do indeed have a 5000 count when running this command in Powershell:

((gp "HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU").Nodeslots).count

My question is: How do you fix that problem? I'm assuming that somehow you need to reduce the 5000 number down to an amount so that when trying to set all folders on my data drives, it will NOT re-enable GROUP BY for hopefully a long time?

Frank

Comment: As it happens, I was the one that asked the question.  I wrote a program to reset that entry to 0, but it didn`t work.  I increased the max slots to 50000, that did not work either.  I think it is some program that I am running which is consuming file handles (or equivalent) like mad.  My further issue is that, at that moment I get blue screen with animation, while Windows does something for 10mins.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately, I (a) don't know how to program, and (b) don't know how or where to check to find out if I'm having a similar situation (though it seems likely).
Maybe some nice person will come on here and help us both.  ¯|_(ツ)_|¯

Comment: The only common folders where `GroupBy` is the default is `Quick Acces` and `Downloads`. It's also the default for `Libraires` which default to the `Folder` *TopView' and group by source folder. Is it `Downloads` that gives you trouble???

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only five native folder types in Windows *Explorer*, *General items, Documents, Pictures, Music,* and *Videos*, as shown below,

[image: Five folder types]

if you set the folder view for each type in the *Folder Options* dialog,

[image: Folder Options dialog]

and apply that view to all folders of that type, setting *Group by* null, then you will no longer see that (annoying, IMHO) grouping.

This also gives you to choose additional columns for each type, such as *Dimensions* and *Camera model* for *Pictures*, and *Authors* and *Title* for *Documents*.

It must be done for each of the five folder types, but does give a more useful view:

[image: Music view]

Comment: There are only five FolderTypes *available through the UI*, but there are many more that exist and are used by default and thus can be considered "Native".

Comment: Here's a PS one-liner that lists the FolderTypes in use by saved views: `('HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags' | gci -s | ? PSChildName -like '{*}').PSChildName.ToLower() | select -unique | %{[PSCustomObject]@{'ID'=$_;'Name'=(gp "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\$_").CanonicalName}}|Out-GridView`

Comment: @KeithMiller, thanks for that scrip! I'd not known there were "folder types" for Search results. Regrettably, Search results always appear first in the unwieldy *Large Thumbnail* view. Is it possible to alter the *x.SearchResults* types to default to *Details* view? If so, *please* publish that on Super User -- it would be a great service to all Windows users!